# Lifetime-management for WinForms with AutoFac - Why MyForm stays "alive"?

Tags: c#, winforms, autofac

I am assuming that in a following scenario my `Form` object should be collected by GC but it is not according to the DotMemory profiler. The surviving objects (`MyView` and `MyPresenter` etc) are listed under the "Survived objects" and Key Retention path for `MyView` is following:

> - MyForm
> - IDisposable[4]
> - Stack
> - Disposer
> - LifetimeScope
> - Container
> - MyServiceLocator
> - `2 unique branches -> "Static reference" and - Object[2040] "Pinning handle"

`MyView` is called by another `Form` which click handler is accessing `MyServiceLocator` property `MyView` and the object is not stored by the `Form`. As a result, `MyView` stays alive even when another click handler is executed. However, There will not be duplicated `MyView` objects if I jump between click handlers.

Is this a valid approach for WinForms with AutoFac and is this expected behavior?

Basically, I want to be able to start `MyView` via click handler such a way that views all required components lifetime is dependent on the view. After something else is clicked on the host form, disposing of `MyView` happens.

To wire my container I am using `AutofacModules` and a custom `MyServiceLocator`. Rest of the app is using constructor injection for all the components.

**MyServiceLocator.cs**

```
public class MyServiceLocator
{
    private static MyServiceLocator _instance;
    private IContainer _container;

    private MyServiceLocator()
    {
        RegisterServices();
    }

    private void RegisterServices()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule<MyAutofacModule>();
        _container = builder.Build();
    }

    public static MyServiceLocator Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new MyServiceLocator());

    public IMyView MyView
    {
        get
        {
            using (var scope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                return _container.Resolve<IMyView>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Registration of the Form and user-controls in the **AutofacModule.cs**

```
public class MyAutofacModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<MyPresenter>().As<IMyPresenter>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<MyModel>().As<IMyModel>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<MyUserControl>().As<IMyUserControl>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<MyView>().As<IMyView>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason for my problem seems to be the lack of taking advance of `ILifetimeScope`. To my understanding, resolving from root container means it will keep references to all objects it has resolved and therefore prevents the GC from cleaning up.

I refactored `MyServiceLocator` into this:

```
public class MyServiceLocator
{
    private static MyServiceLocator _instance;
    private IContainer _container;

    private ILifetimeScope _myViewLifetimeScope;

    private MyServiceLocator()
    {
        RegisterServices();
    }

    private void RegisterServices()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule<MyAutofacModule>();
        _container = builder.Build();
    }

    public static MyServiceLocator Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new MyServiceLocator());

    public IMyView MyView
    {
        get
        {
            _myViewLifetimeScope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope();
            return _myViewLifetimeScope.Resolve<IMyView>();
        }
    }

    public void EndMyViewLifetimeScope()
    {
        _myViewLifetimeScope?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

However, better approaches to my problem are welcomed!